# Not able to access IP CAM on different wireless AP

Tags: router, firewall, lan, wireless-access-point, ip-camera

I've set up a small home network with 1 wired router (TP-LINK TL-R860) and 2 wireless routers (TL-WR841N). Everything seems to be working correctly except for one issue... I have a wireless IP cam that connects to one wireless AP, but it seems to be impossible to access it when connected with the other AP. The cam is using an non-standard port above 40000. I suspect one of the devices is for some reason firewalling access to the port but I can't imagine why since everything is on the local side of the NAT (so, there shouldn't be any firewall'ing going on).

Details of setup:

- 8-port wired router is handling NAT and DHCP server
- both wireless routers have DHCP shut off and are statically assigned their own IP addresses
- wireless routers are connected to the wired router via the LAN ports (nothing on WAN)
- wireless routers have the same SSID

**EDIT:**
I've tried connecting to each wireless AP by specifying a BSSID and I seem to be able to access the camera from either AP now.  I'm wondering if the issue was something transitive due to changes being made during set up   (such as cached DHCP addresses).

Comment: Since all AP have same SSID, ensure that the channel on all routers is not set to auto and there is a wide berth between them. As an example, Router 1 set to channel 1, Router 2 set to channel 6 and Router 3 set to channel 11. For best effectiveness use a WiFi analyzer to get least used channels.

Comment: @GeekyDaddy I don't think that's an issue..  All devices are able to connect to the internet over WAN with no issue.  The only issue is connecting between LAN devices that aren't on the same AP.  So, I'm pretty sure the wireless is working with no issues.

Comment: To clarify, Camera is connected by WiFi to Router A (labelled to distinguish), you are using a computer connected by WiFi to Router B, you cannot make connection to Camera? Are you able to ping camera? You also state that the wireless routers have their DHCP turned off. Are they in the same subnet? 255.255.255.0

Comment: @GeekyDaddy - You are correct.  Yes, they're all on the same subnet 192.168.1.X .  I'll have to get back to you on the ping as I'm not able to test at the moment...